# Show that $B$ is decidable

Tags: decidability

Let $A$ and $B$ be semi decidable languages. Moreover, $A \cup B$ and $A \cap B$ are decidable. I want to show that $B$ is decidable.

Firstly, I would like to know if the following approach works:

First, we can check if $w \in A \cup B$. Since this is decidable, we know that either $w \in A$ or $w \in B$. Now, I wanted to argue that, since $A$ is semi-decidable, so is $A^c$, where $A^c$ is the complement of $A$. Then $A^c \cap B$ is also decidable and wen can simply check if $w \in A^c \cap B$, but I am not sure if that is correct?

Comment: If both $A$ and $B$ are only semi-decidable, this can't be true - consider $A$ to be the language of the halting problem and $B$ its negation (i.e., $B = \overline{A}$). Since $A \cup B$ is the full set, and $A \cap B = \emptyset$, both $A \cup B$ and $A \cap B$ are trivially decidable - but neither $A$ nor $B$ is decidable!

Comment: In your argument, if $A$ is semi-decidable, it does _not_ follow that $A^c$ is semi-decidable - in fact, if $A$ and $A^c$ are both semi-decidable, $A$ is already decidable.

Comment: Well, in general, your proof does not seem to work because you are not really using decidability anywhere.

Comment: @JohannesKloos I do not understand your example with $A$ being the language of the halting problem. I do not get why if $B$ is the complement of $A$, then we have that $A \cup B$ is trivially decidable? The machine can still never halt, even in the full set, can't it?

Comment: Deciding $A \cup B$ is nevertheless trivial - note that to decide whether $x \in A \cup B$, there is no need at all to run any of the machines! You know that $x \in A \cup B$ holds for _all_  $x$, so you can always simply output "true" immediately.

Comment: Is this true for any language and its complement? So for any Language $L$, it holds that $L \cup L^c$ is decidable?

Comment: Yes, this follows easily from the definition of decidable: Pick your favourite model of computation (e.g., Turing machines). A set $X$ is decidable if there is a Turing machine (or program, or algorithm, or whatever your model of computation gives you) that outputs "true" if $x \in X$, and "false" otherwise (other, more convient, return values may be substituted, or you can encode this via reaching a state of the Turing machine - all of these are equivalent). Now, suppose we have some set $X$ such that $x \in X$ for all $X$ - can you give a Turing machine that outputs "true" iff $x \in X$?

Comment: I mean if $x \in X$ for all $X$, we can just return true without even checking or I missunderstood your question. Referring back to the Halting Problem, so we can say that checking if $w \in H \cup H^c$ is like asking: Does the $TM$ halt or not halt on $w$? Where obviously one must be the case.

Comment: Precisely - that's why $L \cup L^c$ is (trivially) decidable for _any_ language. Similarily, $L \cap L^c$ is also decidable for any language, since $L \cap L^c = \emptyset$. Thus, if you choose $B = A^c$ in your claim, it reduces to: "If $A$ is semi-decidable, $A^c$ is decidable", and that's clearly too good to be true.

Comment: @JohannesKloos, ["but neither $A$ nor $B$ is decidable!"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4380891/show-that-b-is-decidable/4381202#comment9156523_4380891). Were you saying the proposition in the question is not correct? Please note that $B$, which is the complement of $A$ (the language of the halting problem), is not semi-decidable.

Comment: ... you're right, @Apass.Jack. I'll cross out the incorect parts of my comments.

Comment: Can't edit those comments anymore. As it turns out, the statement is correct (and has a rather cute proof), and in fact, it can be strengthened: $A$ and $B$ need to be semi-decidable, and both $A \cup B$ and $A \cap B$ need only be co-semi-decidable (i.e., their complement needs to be semi-decidable).

Comment: @JohannesKloos Nice proposition. I just added it to my answer as an exercise.

Comment: @JohannesKloos One last question, as I read this solution  by another student: why can't we simply check if $w \in A \cup B$, and if so, check on two tapes if $w \in A$ or $w \in B$? Since $A,B$ are semi-decidable, a $TM$ will eventually halt.

Comment: What if $w \in A \cap B$, and the machine for $A$ halts first? Would you claim $w \not\in B$?

Comment: No, we could still have $w \in B$, I guess? So we would hope that the $TM$ halts on the $B$  Tape which is not certain. Do you have a trick how to "visualize" such problems easier? Or do you not write down such problems

Comment: Hm, the best I can offer is "imagine you have a bunch of machines, running at different speeds". It's the same kind of thinking you need to work with concurrent programs - basically, "these programs will do what I want, but with the worst possible timing", and then make sure you get the right result no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"First, we can check if $w \in A \cup B$. Since this is decidable, we know that either $w \in A$ or $w \in B$."

I am failing to understand your proof right here.

- By the definition of "decidable", we know that there is a Turing machine that upon input $w$, it will always run to a halt, telling whether $w\in A\cup B$ or not. That is vastly different from "either $w\in A$ or $w\in B$".
- It should be allowed/possible that $w\not \in A\cup B$.

---

Here is an approach to prove. Instead of reasoning on the level of each input to a Turing machine, let us reason on the level of semi-decidability and decidability.

The conditions are

1. $A=(A\setminus B)\sqcup (A\cap B)$ is semi-decidable
2. $B$ is semi-decidable
3. $A\cap B$ is decidable
4. $(A\cup B)^c$ is decidable

Condition 1 and condition 3 imply

5. $A\setminus B$ is semi-decidable.

Condition 4 and condition 5 imply

6. $B^c = (A\cup B)^c \cup (A\setminus B)$ is semi-decidable.

Condition 2 and condition 6 imply $B$ is decidable.

---

**Exercise** (provided by [Johannes Kloos](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4380891#comment9158845_4380891)). Let $A$ and $B$ be semi-decidable languages such that both $A\cup B$ and $A\cap B$ are co-semi-decidable languages. Show that $B$ is decidable.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but I came across this problem again ( spaced repitition :D) and start to finally get it. However, how do we know that $A \setminus B$ is semi-decidable? Is it, because if it was decidable, then A was decidable? Could it also be undecidable?

Comment: Given two languages $X$ and $Y$, if $X$ is semi-decidable and $Y$ is decidable, then $X\setminus Y$ is semi-decidable. Why? Let us enumerate $X$.  However, when a string is enumerated, we check whether it is in $Y$. if it is, we remove it from the enumeration. We get an enumeration of $X\setminus Y$.

Comment: Exercise. Given two languages $X$ and $Y$, if $X$ is semi-decidable and $Y$ is decidable, then $X\cup Y$ is semi-decidable.

Comment: we can just check alternating if $w \in X$ or $w \in Y$. If it halts, we know $x \in X \cup Y$, But it may happen it does never halt, since $X$ is only semi-decidable. This also why, we cannot be sure that if $w \in X \cup Y$ that $w \in Y$.